# retrieve triples with specific predicate without sparql

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I am very new to jena and rdf, so apologies if this is a silly question. I am trying to retrieve all the triples of an rdf model with the same predicate. For example, let my predicate be as follows: `Property p = model.getProperty(<http://someproperty>)`.

I want to find all the triples that have `p` in them. 
I tried using `StmtIterator it = model.listStatements( null, p, null )`. but I get the following warning: `The method listStatements (Resource, Property, RDFNode) is ambiguous for the type Model`.

How should i approach this?

Comment: `model.listStatements( null, p, (RDFNode) null )`

Comment: @AKSW thanks for the reply! that removes the error but still doesnt get correct triples. Im trying to just print triples with specific predicates as follows: `StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements(null, p, (RDFNode) null);
          while (iter.hasNext()) {
           System.out.println("  " + iter.nextStatement());
          } `. It just doesn't print anything. Even though I'm sure that `p` is in the model.

Comment: And I'm sure that the URI doesn't match any of the properties in the model. Please check with `model.listStatements()` first